# Why is filetype not set after :find from autocmd?

Tags: autocmd, filetype, path, find

**Objective**

I want `vi file` to act like `:find file` if `file` doesn't exist.

That is, I want to be able to edit a file by name, without giving a path to the file, from the command line:

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
touch a/b/c/foo.py

vi foo.py
```

When there is no file at all, I don't expect this to work. But when a file does exist, I'd like to be able to get there, just as I could with `:find foo.py`.

**Implementation**

I have set up my path in a [local vimrc](https://github.com/thinca/vim-localrc) file:

```
let proj_dir = expand('<sfile>:p:h')
setlocal path=.
let &path .= ','.proj_dir.'/**'
```

Then I added a function in $MYVIMRC:

```
function! Find_if_not_exist(path)
    if ! filereadable(a:path)
        try
            execute ":find! ".a:path
        catch
        endtry
    endif
endfunction
```

And hooked that in with an autocmd in the same file:

```
autocmd VimEnter * call Find_if_not_exist(expand('<afile>'))
```

This almost works. The file gets loaded if it exists. But when Vim opens, the filetype is unset, there is no syntax hilighting, etc.

If I just type `:e!` again, the reload does get the correct filetype, syntax, etc.

If I type `:find! file` directly from my keyboard, it works.

So why does the `:find!` executed from inside my autocmd not get the correct behavior, and how can I fix it?

**Edit:**

As a temporary fix, I've added `| do BufRead` to the end of my function, which gets at least some of the problem resolved. But I'd still like to know what's going on, and if there's a smoother way to get the file loaded.

Comment: could it be a missing nested?

Comment: What's a nested? :help nested finds `try-nested`, which doesn't seem to apply

Comment: See `:h autocmd-nested`

Comment: Super! That works, although it's about a second slower. Thanks very much!